# Xpath. How to locate Selenium element with same parent?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try to get Selenium Element "value" from that structure:

```
<div class=parent>
  <div class=title>TitleName</div>
  <div>
    <div class=value>ValueName</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Trouble that such structures on page can be a lot, and i know only TitleName. Now i get "parent" element:

```
attr = getSelf().find(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'parent') and .//*[contains(@class,'title')] and .//*[(text()='" + title + "')]]"))
```

and then find "value" element:

```
attr.$(".value");
```

Question: Can I find "value" in one step, only with xpath search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text to locate title element and `following-sibling` to locate the `value`

```
getSelf().find(By.xpath("//div[text()='" + title + "']/following-sibling::div/div"));
```